# increasing modulo problem

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

can someone give me an approach how can i solve this problem?
problem link [increasing modulo](https://codeforces.com/contest/1169/problem/C)
Toad Zitz has an array of integers, each integer is between 0 and m−1 inclusive. The integers are a1,a2,…,an.

In one operation Zitz can choose an integer k and k indices `i1,i2,…,ik` such that  `1≤i1<i2<.. ik ≤ n`. He should then change `aij` to `((aij+1)modm)` for each chosen integer ij. The integer m is fixed for all operations and indices.

Here `xmody` denotes the remainder of the division of x by y.

Zitz wants to make his array non-decreasing with the minimum number of such operations. Find this minimum number of operations.

Edit :
I got one approach but he simplified the (aij+1)mod m to difference of two numbers [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/1169/submission/54780032) Please help